# Load external url from backbean and redirect after clicking <p:button>

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, soap, primefaces

The task I need to accomplish is the following. I need to render a button that gets its target url after making a SOAP request to an external third party (Single Sign In) which returns the url to sign in. I dont want my page's load time to be constrained to this request (which is where im stuck right now). Rather I want the SOAP request to happen only if I click the button (asynchronously) which would take me to the url obtained in a new tab/window. I have tried a bunch of things but so far I have this:

```
<p:button id="ssi" target="_blank" href="#{backbean.soaprequest}" value="button name" widgetVar="ssiButton" onclick="ssiButton.disable()" />
```

This will however wait for the soaprequest to be done then finish rendering the page.

I tried using  but I got nowhere.

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

*Button*

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" 
                 actionListener="#{backbean.soaprequest()}" 
                 oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

*soaprequest()*

```
public void soaprequest() {
    //do your request, replace the link bellow with your login link
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    context.addCallbackParam("url", "http://google.com");//to replace with your link  
}
```

*JS*

```
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
  window.location = args.url;     
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but i get a NPE - at com.stratahealth.shared.common.services.impl.ClauseServiceRequestCache.compoundClauseForServiceProvider(ClauseServiceRequestCache.java:214)

Comment: well this is not related, it seems you have a problem with the service provider.. and the service provider is this http://stratahealth.com/

Comment: im not sure how come thats the problem but i came up with a solution thanks to this post http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1166/speed-up-primefaces-page-load-with-premotecommand-partial-update

Answer (score 0):

in the xhtml part i have

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" layout="inline">
     <p:button id="ssibutton" target="_blank" href="#{backbean.link}" value="Button"/>
</p:outputPanel>

<p:remoteCommand  name="soap_request"
     process="@this"
     update="ssibutton"
     actionListener="#{backbean.url}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {soap_request();});            
</script>
```

On the Backbean

```
private String url;

public Backbean(){
     url = " ";
}

public String getLink(){
     return url;
}

public void url(ActionEvent event){
     //Do soap request to get url
     this.url;
}
```